# nginx and php-fpm returning 404 on static content

Tags: php, nginx, wordpress

I am trying to have nginx on container 1 connect to the php-fpm running wordpress on container 2 on port 9000. It seems to work for dynamically generated content, such a post, but static content such as CSS, JS or images return a 404. What might be causing this?

Please note that the first "server" block is intended to catch all non-HTTP requests and redirect them to HTTPS, while the second is intended to be "catch all" for those sent "mysite.com".

Thank you,

```
http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
        sendfile        on;

        server {
                listen 80;
                listen [::]:80;
                server_name _;
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }

        server {
                listen       80;
                listen       [::]:80;
                listen       443 ssl http2;
                listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
                server_name  localhost;

                ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/privkey.pem;
                ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
                ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
                ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

                location / {
                        root   /usr/local/www/nginx;
                        index  index.html index.htm;
                }
        }

        server {
                server_name             mysite.com
                listen          80;
                listen [::]:80;
                listen 443 ssl http2;
                listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

                ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/privkey.pem;

               location / {
                   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
               }

               location ~ \.php$ {
                       set $my_https $https;
                       if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'https') {
                               set $my_https 'on';
                       }
                       root /var/wordpress;
                       fastcgi_pass 192.168.10.6:9000;
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/wordpress$fastcgi_script_name;
                       include fastcgi_params;
               }
        }
}
```

Comment: You haven't set a `root` statement. What path should container 1 use to access the static files?

Comment: I added the `root` statement. The path `var/wordpress` is the root directory of wordpress on the wordpress container, as reflected above. There was no change in the behavior.

Comment: You seem to have added `root` to the wrong `server` block. But it's still not clear if your Nginx instance can see the WordPress static content. WordPress is a PHP application that requires a webserver to serve the static content. Normally, WordPress in a VM/jail/container/whatever would need, for example, Nginx & php-fpm to serve static/dynamic content.

Comment: I see, I might have had a misunderstanding here. My current system is:
Nginx on container 1 (public facing) -> Nginx on container 2 -> php-fpm also on container 2.
I was hoping to get rid of the middle nginx layer, but perhaps that is not possible?